# Aggregation by Date

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am trying to agregate by time for statistics.

I have object, where i have device_name (PC, Mobile..), time and traffic.

```
public class TrafficRecord extends MongoMorphiaModel {

   public ObjectId id;
   public String device_name;

   public Date time_record;   
   public Long traffic; 

}
```

I am not able to figure out how to write it in the code and agregate that by "Day" or "Hour", of course, there are some tutorials, but not for Morphia.

So expected result is something like:

```
public static class QueryResultStats {

    public String device_name
    public List<Record> avarage_per_something;

}

public static class Record {

    public Long consumption_total;
    public Date start; // Time

}
```

My Query in Morphia Java

```
 Iterator<QueryResultStats> aggregate = ModelMongo_ThingsMobile_CRD.find
                .createAggregation()
                .group(
                       "device_name",
                        Group.grouping(
                                "avarage_per_hour",

                                Group.grouping(
                                        "consumption_total",
                                        Group.sum( "time_record")

                                )
                        )

                )
                .out(
                        QueryResultStats.class,
                        AggregationOptions
                                .builder()
                                .allowDiskUse(false)
                                .maxTime( 5000 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build()
                );
```

Comment: It will be less complicated if you use the modern `LocalDateTime` class instead of the poorly designed and outdated `Date` class. [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thank you, but its not helpful... Stil dont know hot to "split data" by time.